# What should I destroy on angular? How should I?

Tags: angular, lifecycle

I looked at angular documentation, other resources but I didn't find anything.
I work on Angular7. How can I do destruction process?

Comment: I think that your question isn't about how to perform a destruction process, but what to do in that process. Well, 90% of time you won't need an ngOnDestroy, but if, for example, you subscribed to a observable or you are using the event loop cycle (for example, using a timeout), that's the best place to say "I'm going away, I won't use your response!" and you can unsubscribe. You don't need to destroy variables, garbage collector will do it for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
import { Component, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({...})
export class MyComponent implements OnDestroy {
    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        // called when the component gets destroyed
    }
}
```

You can read more about the lifecycle here: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Answer (score 0):

```
See this scenario


import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
  currentUserSub: Subscription;


  getCurrentUser() {
    this.currentUserSub = this.authenticationService.currentUser.subscribe(x => {
      if (x) {
        this.currentUser = x[0].MemberId;
      } else { }
    });



 ngOnDestroy() {
    // unsubscribe to ensure no memory leaks
    this.currentUserSub.unsubscribe();
  }


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

A clean way to unsubscribe from all observables in a component:

```
//declare 
private ngUnsubscribe: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();


//add takeUntill where subscribing to observables 
this.myService.serviceFunction()
                .pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe))
                .subscribe(
                    res => {
                        // use res
                    },
                    err => {}
                );


//unsubscribe all
ngOnDestroy() {
        this.ngUnsubscribe.next();
        this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();
    }
```